# Create a search with wildcard

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to have a two search fields that are able to be searched using a wildcard.

For example: I have a search field where I can search for fruit.  I want to be able to put in "app" or "Ch" and it pull the results out for me.

Most codes I have seen only work if you know what to search for, but my string will always change.

Here is the code below that searches for the fruit but matches it.

```
sheet.Select
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To finalrow
  If IIf(fruit <> "", Cells(i, 1) = fruit, True) Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
    ssheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8).Value = 
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 8)).Value

    dsheet.Select

  End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When only doing one you do not need the IIF from your last question.

You do not need the Copy line.  And avoid Select.

```
finalrow = dsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To finalrow
    If fruit = "" Or InStr(dsheet.Cells(i, 1),fruit) > 0 Then
        ssheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8).Value = dsheet.Range(dsheet.Cells(i, 1), dsheet.Cells(i, 8)).Value
    End If
Next i
```

If you want the IIF, because you simplified it for this question:

```
If IIf(fruit <> "", InStr(dsheet.Cells(i, 1),fruit) > 0, True) Then
```

Comment: Hello, will this make fruits be a wild card? So if I type in "ap" i would get apple apricot etc?

Comment: yes Instr will return a number greater than `0` if that part is found.

Comment: Works Great! Thanks again for your help!